# What to do to fix "no qualified ads found for this request" on iAd?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iad

Somehow I got this error message when testing iAd on the device.

```
"no qualified ads found for this request"
```

What to do to fix it? Anyone has any idea? On the simulator there is no error, it succeeds to show the "Test Advertisement"

UPDATE:

The real problem here is that the delegate to raise the error IS NOT BEING CALLED, on the simulator it works, and on the iPhone it does not. That is the issue.

More details here:

This function is being called in the Simulator:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
```

While this function is being called in the device:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```

I did enable the iAd in the developer's portal and other apps that I test on the device DO show the Test Advertisement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an error to be fixed, but an expected response when no iAd inventory is available.  This may be due to many factors, but the most likely one is that there just aren't a lot of ads in the system right now, seeing as how the service only launched six days ago.  [According to Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/news/archives/2010/june/):

> If you have dedicated a section of
>   your app for an iAd, it's important to
>   incorporate a banner view delegate
>   that will handle common events,
>   including errors. Having the proper
>   delegate to handle errors maintains
>   the visual experience customers have
>   with ads in your app by preventing a
>   blank banner from being displayed when
>   ads are not available. In addition, if
>   your app displays a blank banner when
>   advertisements are not being
>   displayed, your app will be returned
>   to you by the App Review Team for
>   modification before it can be posted
>   to the App Store.

Apple provides boilerplate code for handling this in the ["Working with Banner Views"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-DontLinkElementID_21) section of the iAd Programming Guide.  See also the discussion around [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123259/how-do-i-hide-iad-banners-when-no-ads-are-being-served).

Comment: @sfa - I'm confused.  Ads will properly load in the Simulator, but always error out on the device when testing?  Have you enabled the advertising service for your application?  See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-DontLinkElementID_17

Comment: @sfa - Also it appears from your profile that you are located in Italy.  Note that iAd is only enabled for applications running in North America right now (and possibly only developers based there): http://developer.apple.com/iphone/news/archives/2010/june/#iadjuly1

Comment: thanks Brad, I did enable iAd in my application's developer portal. On the device, other apps do not have this error, only 1 app has this, no matter I am in Italy or not. I am guessing that because I enabled the iAd for this app too soon, when the iTunesConnect problably had the internal error with iAd.

Answer (score 0):

That's an expected error.

The only way to change it is to file bug reports.

Comment: Maybe I should qualify this a little bit.

It's going to be hard to test until the service is ironed out. If bug reports are submitted around this issue, Apple will be more likely to adjust the behavior of the service to make it easier to debug. I wouldn't be surprised if you've gotten different responses from the service already. Good luck!

Comment: I don't think this calls for a bug report.  It's clearly stated that if there is no inventory for the ad to be displayed in your particular application, -bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: will be called on your delegate, at which point you are to hide the banner.  This is how the service is designed.  The actual content of the NSError provided to the delegate shouldn't matter.

Comment: It sounds like you're encountering some strange behavior. If you think it's acceptable then you're right, it doesn't call for a bug report from you. You should consider joining the Apple Developer Program. There's an answer to your question by an Apple engineer on those forums.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error from iTunesConnect when iAd was set without specifying bundleIdentifier. Contact the iTunesConnect team solves the issue.