# iPhone iAd: "no qualified ads found for this request"

Tags: iphone, bundle, identifier, iad, qualified

I have a problem with iAd. I have two apps: let's call them AAA and BBB.
AAA is a new application which is "Waiting for upload" with iAd enabled.
BBB is an existing application which I want to update and is "Waiting for upload" too, with iAd enabled.

iAd in AAA works just fine. In BBB it shows this error in the console:
Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "no qualified ads found for this request"

The same iAd code is used in both apps. Only the provisioning profiles and the bundle identifiers change.
Plus, if I change the bundle identifier of AAA with the one of BBB, it doesn't work! So it seems something related only to the bundle identifier. Apple's problem?

What should I do? I can't get it to work.
I can't change the bundle identifier cause I would not be able to update my existing BBB app.

Comment: You may be interested in the answers to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196880/what-to-do-to-fix-no-qualified-ads-found-for-this-request-on-iad

Comment: Yes I did, but it wasn't helpful. Thanks anyway.

Comment: this is the EXACT same problem i am facing.
except my problem started as soon as my application state changed to "in review", the application is in the app store now, and i am getting 0 requests, and ad is not working.
Did u find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth: I have similar issues with my FlashLight4 FREE app. Sometimes iads load just fine and typically once iAds started load fine I continue to see inventory filled for quite a while (5min).

Later then restart my app and I have zero fill-rate - see the same error as described in above entry. Once that happens typically I seem *never* to get any iAds filled; I have to stop-restart my app several times and then if I get lucky fill-rate goes up.

So I *guess* this is due to general low fill-rate in iAds.. but who knows.. AAPL is not exactly helpful in telling much..

Comment: It was indeed just a general low fill-rate. It solved itself after a while. Thanks for your answer!