# Can I have iAds and In-app Purchase to remove ads in one single app?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, iad, appstore-approval

According to Apple Advertising guide: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#advertising

I have confusion about the this point:

> Apps that contain empty iAd banners will be rejected

Does this mean that I cannot have iAds and In-App purchase to remove the iAds from my App for upgrading from Lite version to Pro version?

Can anybody suggest how to handle this situation where i have Lite version and Pro version?? Do I need to have 2 apps in App Store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This particular point refers to showing iAd banners when they haven't loaded yet.  iAd banners should be hidden until content has arrived.  If you show an ad banner when there is no content, you may get a review [rejection worded similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123259/how-do-i-hide-iad-banners-when-no-ads-are-being-served):

> We've completed the review of your application; however, we cannot post this version to the App Store because it displays an empty iAd banner when ad content is not available. The banner within the app should be hidden whenever ad content is not being served by iAd. We have included additional details below to help explain the issue. We hope that you'll consider revising and resubmitting your application.
>
> To handle the case where ad content is not available, you will need to implement a banner view delegate. An example code snippet is included here for your convenience. Additionally, you may wish to review the section "Working with Banner Views" of the iAd Programming Guide for specific details: https://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html

The `ADBannerView` will call `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` on its delegate.  This is your cue to show the ad banner.  The banner should not be shown until there is an ad loaded.

To answer your last question, you can have a separate Lite and Pro version without any problems.  Or, you can go 'freemium' where you have a single application and the user does an IAP to remove the ads.

Comment: Thanks... Yes AppStore do approve such apps.. My app is just got approved.. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ui-maker-design-mobile-app/id791072042?mt=8

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are allowed to show Ads (iAd or anyone else') and turn them off if the user makes an In-Ap Purchase. There are no Terms of Service that disallow that.

One simplistic implementation would be to check a value saved in `NSUserDefaults`. If the value is NOT there show Ads, and if the value IS there do not. You set that value when the user makes the In-App purchase.

Comment: Thanks... Yes AppStore do approve such apps.. My app is just got approved.. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ui-maker-design-mobile-app/id791072042?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my Question is **YES**. Finally I have my app on AppStore: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ui-maker-design-mobile-app/id791072042?mt=8

It does allows to have In-app purchase to make iAds Free version. Thanks to Apple.... :)

Here both answers are correct.. But unfortunately, I can accept only one... so +1 to both... :)