# iOS: Using auto-renewable subscription to remove ads

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I want to create an Auto-renewable subscription for my app to enable the feature of removing the ads. (one year period)
Is is possible? Would it be approved?

A non-renewable can work as well but I don't want to manage users and subscriptions on my own server, I would like to have a subscription attached to an apple id.

Thanks

Comment: The [review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies) do not preclude this, as long as you meet *"Apps may only use auto-renewing subscriptions for periodicals (newspapers, magazines), business Apps (enterprise, productivity, professional creative, cloud storage), and media Apps (video, audio, voice), or the App will be rejected"* See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20925507/3001761

Comment: I thinks this question become actual again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've previously applied to use an auto-renewing subscription for a business app, and was rejected (I've seen reports from others that this has been the case well). Even though the guidelines list the 'business' usage is acceptable, Apple are clearly aiming them at periodicals only.

There are [other](http://www.marco.org/2013/12/02/auto-renewable-subscriptions) issues with them to consider as well.

The way I handle it at the moment is by using multiple in-app purchases for various time periods (1 month / 3 months / 12 months etc), hold an expiry date on the device and check that on each app launch. When it has passed, the users are then presented with a re-purchase screen. They can also purchase multiple time-packs which further extends the expiry date.